# Why isn't the Error List in Visual Studio 2017 showing all errors and how do we fix it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have two coworkers that just installed Visual Studio 2017.  On some solutions, they're not seeing errors in the Error List when they rebuild or run a solution.  All of these solutions were originally created in Visual Studio 2015; don't know if that matters.  On the Output tab, they can see the errors along with warnings, but when they go to the Error List tab, it says 0 errors.  I've found examples of other people having this problem, but can't find any solutions:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130531/error-list-does-not-show-all-errors.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/17823/build-failing-error-not-showing-in-error-list-wind.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44541/error-list-still-not-working.html

How do I get the Error List so it shows errors again?

Comment: I supose you have activated the error and Warnings buttons on the top left corner of the window and set the dropdowns to Entire Solution and Build + intelisense. Is the Projekt still starting or denied the Errors starting your Solution?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar, but in my case it was my fault.
On the top of the errorlist, there is a combo box.
In my case, it was at the state of "Only build", but in order to see all errors, switch it to "Build+IntelliSense". Maybe this simple solution might help some of you.
In VisualStudio forums, they recommend you to disable lightweight solution:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26498/erorr-list-not-updating.html